# AVPlayer Interrupt Notifications not working

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I am using avplayer notification for handling interruption but it seems that notification are not getting fired

```
 private func setupNotifications() {
    let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleInterruption), name: AVAudioSession.interruptionNotification, object: nil)
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerDidRecieveError(_:)), name: .AVPlayerItemNewErrorLogEntry, object: nil)
     notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerDidRecieveError(_:)), name: .AVPlayerItemFailedToPlayToEndTime , object: nil)
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerDidRecieveError(_:)), name: .AVPlayerItemPlaybackStalled , object: nil)  
}
```

Comment: i am using avplayer to stream audio

Answer (score 1):

I am using something like:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(self.playerDidFinishPlaying(note:)),name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemNewErrorLogEntry, object: player?.currentItem)

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(self.playerDidFinishPlaying(note:)),name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemFailedToPlayToEndTime, object: player?.currentItem)

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(self.playerDidFinishPlaying(note:)),name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemPlaybackStalled, object: player?.currentItem)

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(self.playerDidFinishPlaying(note:)),name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player?.currentItem)

@objc func playerDidFinishPlaying(note: NSNotification){
        print("Finished")
    }
```

Comment: yes, this notification is working....but rest is not working.....need those 3 for error handling

Comment: it was very simple to see other options... Check my edited answer.

Comment: just create a new function for each like playerDidFinishPlaying. It is so simple...